# Octave: Sum all elements except first column?

Tags: matrix, sum, octave

In Octave, how do I get the sum of all the elements of a matrix `a` excluding those in the first column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(a(1:end, 2:end)(:))
```

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but maybe someone could find this alternative useful.
You can also do `sum(sum(a(:, 2:end)))`